# IJulia with SymPy not working

Tags: python, math, sympy

IJulia symbolitc mathematics is not working with SymPy and PyCall as described in http://mth229.github.io/symbolic.html.

Example:

```
using SymPy
x = Sym("x")
```

produces the following Error Message:

```
PyError (PyImport_ImportModule) <type 'exceptions.TypeError'>
TypeError("unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'NoneType' and 'NoneType'",)
  File "C:\PYTHON27\lib\site-packages\sympy\__init__.py", line 35, in <module>
    from .polys import *
  File "C:\PYTHON27\lib\site-packages\sympy\polys\__init__.py", line 5, in <module>
    from . import polytools
  File "C:\PYTHON27\lib\site-packages\sympy\polys\polytools.py", line 52, in <module>
    from sympy.polys.domains import FF, QQ
  File "C:\PYTHON27\lib\site-packages\sympy\polys\domains\__init__.py", line 9, in <module>
    from . import finitefield
  File "C:\PYTHON27\lib\site-packages\sympy\polys\domains\finitefield.py", line 7, in <module>
    from sympy.polys.domains.groundtypes import SymPyInteger
  File "C:\PYTHON27\lib\site-packages\sympy\polys\domains\groundtypes.py", line 13, in <module>
    from .pythonrational import PythonRational
  File "C:\PYTHON27\lib\site-packages\sympy\polys\domains\pythonrational.py", line 12, in <module>
    from sympy.printing.defaults import DefaultPrinting
  File "C:\PYTHON27\lib\site-packages\sympy\printing\__init__.py", line 3, in <module>
    from .pretty import pager_print, pretty, pretty_print, pprint, \
  File "C:\PYTHON27\lib\site-packages\sympy\printing\pretty\__init__.py", line 3, in <module>
    from .pretty import (pretty, pretty_print, pprint, pprint_use_unicode,
  File "C:\PYTHON27\lib\site-packages\sympy\printing\pretty\pretty.py", line 14, in <module>
    from .stringpict import prettyForm, stringPict
  File "C:\PYTHON27\lib\site-packages\sympy\printing\pretty\stringpict.py", line 17, in <module>
    from .pretty_symbology import hobj, vobj, xsym, xobj, pretty_use_unicode
  File "C:\PYTHON27\lib\site-packages\sympy\printing\pretty\pretty_symbology.py", line 426, in <module>
    '-->': ('-->', U('EM DASH') + U('EM DASH') +

while loading C:\Users\eugenio\.julia\v0.3\SymPy\src\SymPy.jl, in expression starting on line 761
while loading In[2], in expression starting on line 1

 in pyerr_check at C:\Users\eugenio\.julia\v0.3\PyCall\src\exception.jl:58
 in pyimport at C:\Users\eugenio\.julia\v0.3\PyCall\src\PyCall.jl:85
 in include at boot.jl:245
 in include_from_node1 at loading.jl:128
 in reload_path at loading.jl:152
 in _require at loading.jl:67
 in require at loading.jl:51
```

Setup: 
- Windwos 8.1, 64bit 
- Anaconda Python installed (... how would it work with PythonXY or just Python 2.7 on C:\Python27 ?) 
- Julia vers. 0.3.1 
- PyCall vers. 0.4.9 
- SymPy vers. 0.2.19

Answer (score 2):

This looks like a bug in SymPy (the Python library, not the Julia library), which I have opened at https://github.com/sympy/sympy/issues/8163.

The issue seems like it might come up if you can't import `unicodedata` in Python. Can you run `import unicodedata` either directly in Python or using PyCall?

Comment: Thx asmeurer,

in IJulia:

 using PyCall
 import unicodedata

returns error:

 unicodedata not found
 while loading In[7], in expression starting on line 2
 in require at loading.jl:47



in IPython runnung "import unicodedata" returns no error (installed with PythonXY).

Comment: I have https://github.com/sympy/sympy/pull/8164 which fixes this (you will not get unicode pretty printing without `unicodedata`, but at least SymPy is importable and usable).